# The real Richard Castle as an author

Tags: castle

In the TV show *Castle*, the books **Richard Castle** writes are real. They are best-sellers. But who is the real author of those books? Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: I am pretty sure the books in the TV show are just props. Yes, they released Nikki Heat books after the show became popular, but in your question it's not really clear if you are talking about them, or the actual books shown in the show?

Comment: Books with the same titles are available for purchase online. So I am asking about the authors of those books that are available for us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](http://romancingthetv.com/2010/06/who-writes-richard-castle-books/), the authorship of the Richard Castle books is not clearly revealed. However, certain clues lend credibility to the fact that Tom Straw, a published mystery crime writer, is responsible for them.

Farther down, in the list of comments, is this one.

> Aparna
> November 15, 2014 at 7:57 am
>
> By the way, Nathan at Comic ocn [sic] confirmed your analysis that it is Tom Straw who is writing the books. This is the video of the comic con conversation:
>
> He talks about the incident at 34:38

Comment: For anyone who hasn't the time to watch the video, Nathan Fillion does NOT say that Tom Straw writes the books. He says there was a person on set in an episode who wrote the books, and it's stated elsewhere online (although not anywhere officially) that Tom Straw was present in the episode he mentions. So while it does seem like it may be true, Fillion did *not* flatly state it in the way the commenter suggests he did.

Answer (score 1):

If you look on Tom Straw's [website](https://www.tomstraw.com/), it says the following:

> TOM STRAW published his first mystery novel, The Trigger Episode, in 2007. Subsequently, writing as Richard Castle, he authored seven more crime novels, all of which became New York Times Bestsellers. Buzz Killer is Tom Straw’s first book under his own name since that blockbuster Nikki Heat series.

Comment: mention source of the information